# Setting a notification to fire at a specific time in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications, notificationmanager

I'm trying to get a notification to fire at a specific time. It occurs to me that I wouldn't have to use an Alarm Manager since I have the "alCal" variable that sets the time. Would it be possible to convert alCal into a Long and use it instead of `System.currentTimeMillis();` as the fireTime variable? If so, how would I convert alCal into a Long? Here's my current code:

```
            //---use the AlarmManager to trigger an alarm---
        AlarmManager aMan = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            //---get current date and time---
        Calendar alCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        //---sets the time for the alarm to trigger---                       
        alCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);            
        alCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 41);                
        alCal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        Intent noteIntent = new Intent(this, Splash.class);
        PendingIntent pendI = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, noteIntent, 0);
        long fireTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String noteBody = "notification body";
        String noteTitle = "notification title";
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.noteicon, noteTitle, fireTime);
        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, noteTitle, noteBody, pendI);
        note.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        noteman.notify(uniqueID, note);
        //---sets the alarm to trigger--- 
        aMan.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendI); 
        finish();
```

ok, looks like I can't convert alCal into a long, so I guess I do have to use an AlarmManager. So given the above code, how do I modify it so that the AlarmManger fires the notification at the specified time? I'm new to Android and Java, so I'm not really seeing the sloution. I would think alCal has to be called somewhere in the new Notification call, but I don't know how to do that. Eclipse says I can't just swap fireTime for alCal, so I don't know what to try next.

Comment: You *are* "converting" alCal to long with `alCal.getTimeInMillis`... What is your question?

Comment: You posted the similar question 2 hour before and i answered it.. Did you try that solution? And i am not seeing that question now. Did you delete it?

Comment: Yes, I did delete the question, because I thought this was a better question. BUt maybe it isn't. I did try your solution and putting a date variable in there crashed the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It occurs to me that I wouldn't have to use an Alarm Manager

Yes, you would.

> since I have the "alCal" variable that sets the time.

That is a `java.util.Calendar` object. On its own, it will not execute your code (such as displaying a `Notification`) at a particular time.

> Would it be possible to convert alCal into a Long and use it instead of System.currentTimeMillis(); as the fireTime variable? If so, how would I convert alCal into a Long?

Call [`getTimeInMillis()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29).

Bear in mind that your code is not "Setting a notification to fire at a specific time in Android". It will display a `Notification` immediately, plus set an alarm to invoke an activity at a certain time in the future.

Comment: of course you are correct on everything that you've pointed out. I'm new to Android (I think you can tell). What I'm trying to do Set a notification to fire at a specific time in Android, and I've gotten the bulk of the above code from various places, and you're right, what this code does is fire the notification right away and then set an alarm. Would you tell me how to modify the code so that the alarm sets the notification to fire? I imagine that I'd have to put the AlCal variable in the new Notification call, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @kirktoon1882: "Would you tell me how to modify the code so that the alarm sets the notification to fire?" -- use a `PendingIntent` with `AlarmManager` that invokes something else (e.g., a `BroadcastReceiver`) that, in turn, raises the `Notification`.

Comment: I looked at http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/displaying-status-bar-notifications-android but it looks overly complicated for what I want to do. This tutorial allows the user to set the alarm. I don't want to do that. I just want to give a static time to fire the notification. Is it bad coding to put the alarmManager, notification and Broadcast receiver all in the same activity class? this tutorial has three classes, that seems like overkill to me.

Comment: @kirktoon1882: the `BroadcastReceiver` has to be in a separate class, unless you only want the `Notification` to be raised while the activity is in the foreground -- you need your `BroadcastReceiver` to be registered in the manifest. The `Notification` is not a class you write, but one from the OS that you use. Likewise for `AlarmManager`.